# Permission issue accessing Netatalk share on OS X

Tags: macos, ubuntu, afp, netatalk

I have two users in Ubuntu. My first was me and I am the owner of the folder in question. The second is my wife. Netatalk is running and we can both see the folder on the network. I can access it but she cannot. She gets an error in OS X:

> … you don't have permission to see its contents

I have use `chmod 777` on the folder but it made no difference. Any ideas?

---

The directory in question is a mounted harddrive at `/media/ourPhotos`

#### `ls -lh /media/`

I am trying to share "Mir Yannick", shared group is "shapiras"

```
total 112K
drwx------ 1 isaac isaac     24K Dec  1 10:52 Belboz the Magnificent
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  shapiras    7 Aug 18 16:17 floppy -> floppy0
drwxrwxr-x 3 root  shapiras 4.0K Dec 16 03:28 floppy0
drwx------ 1 isaac isaac     48K Dec  1 10:51 Frobozz Magic Memory Device
drwx------ 1 isaac isaac     28K Aug 20 16:23 Mir Yannick
drwxrwxr-x 3 root  shapiras 4.0K Aug 20 09:01 Network Trash Folder
drwxrwxr-x 3 root  shapiras 4.0K Aug 20 09:01 Temporary Items
```

#### `AppleVolumes.default`

```
/davidtennant Tardis allow:isaac cnidscheme:dbd options:usedots,upriv,tm
/media cnidscheme:dbd allow:isaac,jessica options:usedots,upriv
/media/Mir\ Yannick allow:jessica options:usedots,upriv
```

#### `df -T`

```
Filesystem     Type      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdh1      ext4     1939812036 1193632920 649089428  65% /
udev           devtmpfs    3047700         12   3047688   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       1222604        900   1221704   1% /run
none           tmpfs          5120          0      5120   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs       3056500        740   3055760   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1      fuseblk  1953512444 1504702472 448809972  78% /media/Mir Yannick
/dev/sdg1      fuseblk   976759804  873042100 103717704  90% /media/Belboz the Magnificent
/dev/sda1      fuseblk   976759804  703015860 273743944  72% /media/Frobozz Magic Memory Device
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

netatalk by default share out home directory, which I guess that is what you are using.

For your wife to connect to your ubuntu home directory on OS X

1. Open **Finder**
2. Click **Go** on top menu bar
3. Click **connect to Server...***
4. Type in **afp://ubuntu-server-ip**, click **Connect**
5. A box should pop up ask for **Name** and **Password**, type in **your** username and password

To share common folder between different users:

1. On Ubuntu create a new group with

   ```
   addgroup sharefolder
   ```
2. Add all users to that group

   ```
   adduser username1 sharefolder
   adduser username2 sharefolder
   ```
3. Umount the ntfs external drive, then remount it.

   At this point, it is very dependent on how package mount.ntfs or ntfs-3g is built. It may automatically pick up the new *sharefolder* group assigned to user and set it in acl list. Which is not obvious in *ls -l < mount point >*. If that is the case, restarting *netatalk* will fix the issue.

   If the above do not apply, then it can be fixed by mount option describe below

   1. Find out GID of group *sharefolder*

      ```
      id -g sharefolder
      ```
   2. Set GID when mounting (assume sharefolder gid=1004)

      ```
      mount -f ntfs /dev/sdb1 <mount point> -o gid=1004
      ```
4. Restart netatalk

   ```
   service netatalk restart
   ```

Comment: Its not the home directory, its a mounted hard drive. I didn't realize that was significant. My apologies, I have edited my answer.

Comment: But can your wife access that share with my method?

Comment: Well she can access her home folder fine, thats the method we where using actually. And she can see the folder in question too, but it got a red circle on it in osx and says she does not have permission to access content.

Comment: She has to "umount" her home folder, then "mount" your folder with your login. You can only use one credential with a server at a time. You cannot connect as A to Folder-A and as B to Folder-B at the same time to a single server.

Comment: Are you telling me that netatalk is not capable of sharing the same folder to two different accounts?

Comment: I am on my mac, connected as Foo to folders A and B. She is on her mac  and connected as Bar to folder C; at the same time, but from two different computers. Why can't it be `Foo -> A, B` and `Bar -> C, B` at the same time?

Comment: Netatalk is capable to handle multiple accounts and folders.

Comment: Well the issue is that right now Foo can access B but Bar can't. I've set B to 777 to no effect and can't think of anything else to do. Foo is the owner of that folder, but that should not matter.

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know result. Pay attention to step 3, there is a semi-colon(:) right before the group name sharefolder.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still new to linux, and step 3 confuses me, where would I put the path to the folder in that command?

Comment: Sorry, formatting error.

Comment: in progress, will let you know result as soon as it finishes

Comment: Same thing. No change.

Comment: Oh and I restarted the daemon as well.

Comment: Please update question with content of /etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default and output of "ls -lh /media"

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: It looks like chown did nothing to change the ownership of the mounted drives. Maybe thats a hint.

Comment: Which folder is the mounted one? I don't see "ourPhoto" in your update.

Comment: Its Mir Yannick. I was just using ourPhoto as a hypothetical, but then again this tread has gotten real.

Comment: Mir Yannick is basically a hd from my bad old windows days, and contains about 1tb of photos.

Comment: Updated, netatalk won't work. I updated with samba config info.

Comment: Aww... really? No netatalk? I was hoping we could both use the afp service for timemachine. Can't do that with samba.

Comment: You can keep netatalk running, there is no conflict between them.

Comment: Guys, please note that we also have [chat] for longer discussions. Try and keep the comment thread somewhat small. Thank you. /cc @Fresheyeball

Comment: Ok so this has messed everything up. Not only does Samba not play nice along side Netatalk, but now I don't have authorization to access any of my harddrives. My whole system is screwed.

Comment: They don't even show up under /dev

Comment: Let do this in chat. Craeting a room "access netatalk share on osx permission issue"

Comment: room : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6756/access-netatalk-share-on-osx-permission-issue

Comment: I got it working. I rebooted unmounted and remounted the drives to new locations.

Comment: You've been a huge help, and put in big effort. Please add that possible fix and I will award you the bounty.

Comment: Updated. I hope it reflect what you did for the final touch.

Comment: I did not use Samba. Netatalk did work. The permissions problem had to do with the manner in which the drives where mounted. I don't know why it was the case, or how remounting them from the command-line instead of the from the ui made a difference, but what ended up working is still contradictory to your answer.

Comment: Can you post your current AppleVolumes.default and ls -lh "mount point"? The answer may be in them. Also the command line you use to mount.

Comment: After reviewing previous answer, updated base on the result of netatalk work after reboot.

Comment: @Fresheyeball any feedback or comment?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your directory permissions are incorrect. Netatalk cannot override system permissions, that is, the directory must be accessible to the user as if they were on the computer. In this case, you own the drive "isaac", the group is also "isaac", and have the perm 0700. You need to change the group of the folder to one that "jessica" is in, and change the permissions to 0770. This will allow anybody in the group rwx. If you have files on the drive that only you want access to, change the perm to 0700, so the group has no access.

I could be wrong, but I believe netatalk needs x permission on a folder to show the contents.